# setSelectedItem to jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

To make an item I have some jComboboxes in a jform where you can select some options and when you want to edit something some values of an object (toString) are displayed in a jcombobox in another jform with the value selected. But it doesn't want to display the values in the combobox. I want to show the name + firstname in the combobox (toString)

```
try {
    ak = pdb.seekPerson(v.getBuyerId());
    coKoper.removeAllItems();
} catch (ApplicationException ae) {
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ae.getMessage());
}

initiateCombo(); //adds the objects tot the combo
coBuyer.setSelectedItem(ak.toString());
}

    private void initiateCombo() {
        PersonDB pdb = new PersonDB();
        try {
            ArrayList<Persons> buyer = pdb.seekAllBuyers();
            for (Persons p : buyer) {
                coBuyer.addItem(p);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, do you try to override the `toString()` method of your class `Persons` ?
Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return name + " " + firstname ;
}
```

Moreover, use `setSelectedItem` like this (I suppose `ak` is an instance of `Persons`):

```
coBuyer.setSelectedItem(ak);
```

Don't forget to override the `equals(Object o)` method ;)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if( o instanceof Persons ){
    boolean check = /* here your own code*/;
    return check;
  }
  return false ;
}
```

Comment: where do I have to override the equals method? in the class of the form or in class Persons?

Comment: Thanks for your help already but I don't know what I have to write in the equals method so if you could please help me.

Comment: @Boe Can't help you for this without the code, summarily you must check if `o` is like `this` in my sample.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the coBuyer combobox contains Persons objects. You retrieve the Persons object you want to select and store it in ak.

The combobox is going to display the toString() method of the Persons object. By default, this displays Object.toString(). You need to @Override toString() in the Persons class and have it return name + firstname, or whatever you want the combobox to display.

Comment: I have this
@Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder(name + " " + firstname + "\n");

        return bf.toString();
    }